# Passing variable into Map key Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I'm doing this web page where I pass in my request an attribute containing a Map. 
I'm using Jquery to get the value of this map according to the key. 
I have the following code :

```
jQuery("font#clickable").click(function() {
var t = $(this).text(); 
var operation = '${regle.words[t].operation}';
alert(operation);
});
```

I'll get the contained text on click and store it in the "t" variable.

Following is the description of the different elements:

- "regle": Is the attribute on the request.
- "words" : Map of "String,Word".
- A "Word" contains different attributes as text, operation, color.. (all Strings)

The problem is when I try to get the value of the ***operation*** according to the word clicked (var operation = '${regle.words[t].operation}') I get an empty result in alert().

var operation is empty

When I pass directly the string on the "words" map key :

```
var operation = '${regle.words['that'].operation}';
```

I can get the operation. The operation value is then "Substitution". I have tried the following :

```
var t = 'that';
```

But same results I get an empty string. The problem is when I pass a variable on the key and not a String.

Does anyone have an idea how to sole the problem?

Comment: After many test I realized that the if we want to pass a variable in the key of the map it has to be a request variable or a page variable. If I try the following : <c:set value="that" var="mot"/> and the I make var operation = '${regle.words[mot].operation}'; I obtain the result desired ("Substitution" ). The problem is now how to pass a variable of javaScript on the value of the JSTL set.

Comment: There is another possible solution which is to transform  '${regle.words[mot].operation}'; into a string replacing mot by it's value var newString =  'Trying' + mot. Which will give me var newString = 'Trying that'. I've tried the function eval("String"); But no results yet..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
var operation = '${' + regle.words[t].operation + '}';
```

For example, if `regle.words[t].operation` give you the string "foo" then the result in `operation` would be the string "${foo}".

However, if what you actually wanted was for `operation` to be the string "${regle.words['that'].operation}" then you should use the following

```
var operation = "${regle.words['" + t + "'].operation}";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer actually is :

    '${regle.words['that'].operation}' 

Who gives me a string. When I try your answer I get

" + regle.words[t].operation +"  on the alert, but I should get the operation attributed to the word "t" passed as key on the map "words" which is a String

Comment: Hi I think I was maybe explaining wrong my problem. Actually when I evaluate for example '${regle.words['that'].operation}', the result is a string "Substitution". If I do var t = 'that' and I evaluate now '${regle.words[t].operation}' the result is an empty string. Your second answer give me the same result as the second evaluation which is an empty string

Comment: I have also tried the following but with the same result ..  var t_str = "'" + t + "'";        var operation = '${regle.words[t_str].operation}';    @Jamiec Thank you for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

So after looking in internet for hours I realized that what I want to do cannot be mixed. I'm trying to pass a JavaScript variable into a JSP page in a EL. This cannot be accomplish and the only way if I'm not wrong is by an attribute in the  request. What I did is maybe not really clean but is the only way I could solve my problem. I put my variable into a hidden input which I pass in my post request. And then I can use it as I desire. Thank you anyway for your help.